# Update value from 0 to 1 in mysql table with checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

MYSQL Table structure

```
Name    Type            Collation         Attributes    Null    Default
code    varchar(2)      utf8_unicode_ci                  No     
name    varchar(255)    utf8_unicode_ci                  No     
checkbox  tinyint(1)                                     Yes       NULL
```

PHP

```
$countryiso = mysql_query("SELECT distinct name as name FROM location_country where code NOT IN('A1','A2','AP','EU') order by name");
echo '<table>';
echo '<th>Country</th><th> Add/Remove </th>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($countryiso)) {
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td><input type="checkbox"></td>';
 echo '</tr>';
}
 echo '</table>';
```

I need to update a value from column checkbox from 0 to 1 when i check the checkbox in my php backend. How do i do this with php and mysql only? Please no Jquery.

Comment: Use pure javascript then.

Comment: @u_mulder I am a noob on this could you please help me with an answer based on my code?

Comment: @Adrian Your code shows just the readout. No Update method. Show some effort, and show what you arleady tried.

Comment: Your code is for server side. If you want some actions on client-side - then you have to learn javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use JavaScript you need use SUBMIT button in the end of the form:

```
$countryiso = mysql_query("SELECT distinct name as name FROM location_country where code NOT IN('A1','A2','AP','EU') order by name");
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo '<table>';
echo '<th>Country</th><th> Add/Remove </th>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($countryiso)) {
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="' . $row['code'] . '"></td>';
 echo '</tr>';
}
 echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit"></td></tr>';
 echo '</table>';
 echo '</form>';
```

Then:

```
if(isSet($_POST['check']) && $_POST['check'])
{
    foreach($_POST['check'] as $check)
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE yourtable SET checkbox = 1 WHERE code = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($check) . "'");
        // any message of success
    }
}
```

**BUT** don't forget that **mysql_** will be deprecated and deleted in the future. Use **PDO** or **mysqli_** for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's similar with this i wanted to do, but doesn't work. When i check the checkbox and submit it doesn't change the value in the table column.

Comment: Tried moving it in front and when i click submit the form dissapears, but still doesn't work.

Comment: DId you edit yourtable in UPDATE queryto your real name table?

Comment: Use print instead of mysql_query to dump it.

Comment: I have re-edited your answer managed to get it done. Thanks, you were very close.